# Detecting the monitor mode

Tags: display, tv

I think I want something that's not possible. Still, without asking I'd never know for sure... :-)

I have a Samsung T260HD monitor. It has a resolution of 1920x1200 and also has a build-in TV tuner. So, when I'm not using my computer, I can still use it as a nice television. (And I also have a TV card in my computer which I can use when I do want to use my computer.) This monitor also has it's own remote, plus a SCART connector to e.g. connect a video recorder or DVD player.

I just wonder if it's possible somehow if the computer can detect if the monitor is in TV mode, DVD (Scart) mode or computer mode. And maybe even switch the monitor mode if possible. That way, when I turn on my computer or e.g. press some computer key, the monitor would switch from TV mode to computer mode...

Anyway, the monitor didn't come with any such software so I don't think it's possible. It would be cool if this was somehow possible, though...

(No, I don't need another monitor. Before I recently bought this monitor, I didn't even need the TV functionality it has.)

Comment: is it a laptop ?

Comment: Nope, dual-monitor desktop. :-) But only one of them can be controlled through a remote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have to manually switch the mode on the TV.

EDIT : Since this is SuperUser.com, I'm going to put a bit of effort in trying to help you achieve your dreams of saving 1 button press.

Your objective is to :

1. When you press the power button on the computer, the TV turns on, and at the same time, switches to PC mode.

Suggested way of achieving this :

Get an electronic infrared kit - the one that can send out programmed infrared beams - it's pretty cheap. Find it at your local electronics hobby store.

Program it to send 2 instructions - the infrared commands for "Turn on my TV!" and "Switch to PC mode!". Do not, I repeat, do not send the command for "Autobots, transform!".

Wire the trigger of the infrared kit to the power button on your PC. Set it to trigger when the button is pressed.

Voila.

Comment: That might actually work too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the only input is through the TV, then your choices are limited to press the button like normal, or rig up an infra-red device to send out the same signals as your remote. The latter is... not worth it, assuming it even exists.